# SQL Server Time out when selecting and deletion many rows (approx 24000) for many users

Tags: java, sql-server

I get a time out exception when I run the below code in java with SQL server. It works fine for 1 user but when I load test with multiple concurrent user (only 10) it gives me time out error. Please help.

```
public void deleteAgmtWrkldDetail(Integer agreementId, Integer groupId, List<String> months, Integer staffId, String tempId, int userId,  String agmtNo, String staffCatCode,
        List<BigDecimal> workLoadList, AgmtWorkloadSummary wSummary) {

    Integer manSchId = insertOrUpdateManningSchedule(agreementId, groupId, staffId, tempId, userId, agmtNo);
    if(months != null && months.size() > 0) {           
        List<AgmtWorkloadDetail> existsWorkloadDetailList = workloadDao.getAllAgmtWorkloadDetailByScheduleIdAndMonthsAndCategory(manSchId, months, staffId, staffCatCode);
        existsWorkloadDetailList.forEach(x -> {
            workloadDao.remove(x);
            });
        }
    for (int k = 0; k < months.size() && k < workLoadList.size(); k++) {
        AgmtWorkloadDetail wlDetail = new AgmtWorkloadDetail();
        BigDecimal workload = BigDecimal.ZERO;
        try {
            workload = ((BigDecimal) workLoadList.get(k));
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

        wlDetail.setSummaryId(wSummary.getSummaryId());
        wlDetail.setWorkloadDate(new Integer(months.get(k)));
        wlDetail.setWorkloadUnit(WorkloadUnit.WEEK.getValue());
        wlDetail.setWorkload((workload != null ? workload : new BigDecimal(0)));
        wlDetail.setStaffCatCode(staffCatCode);
        wlDetail.setCreateDate(LocalDateTime.now());
        wlDetail.setCreateUser(userId);
        wlDetail.setUpdateDate(LocalDateTime.now());
        wlDetail.setUpdateUser(userId);
        workloadDao.persist(wlDetail);
        }
    }
```

Below is the code for insertOrUpdateManningSchedule ()

```
public Integer insertOrUpdateManningSchedule (Integer agreementId, Integer groupId, Integer staffId, String tempId, int userId, String agmtNo) {
    AgmtManSch manningSchedule = manningScheduleDao.getAllAgreementManningScheduleByAgmtIdAndGroupId(agreementId, groupId);

    final LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
    if (manningSchedule != null) {
    manningSchedule.setSubmitDate(LocalDateTime.now());
    manningSchedule.setHibVersion(manningSchedule.getHibVersion()+1);
    manningSchedule.setUpdateDate(now);
    manningSchedule.setUpdateUser(userId);  
    workloadDao.merge(manningSchedule);
    } else {
        // create a new manning schedule as there is no recored with the given project Id
        AgmtManSch agmtManSch = new AgmtManSch();
        agmtManSch.setGroupId(groupId);
        agmtManSch.setAgmtId(agreementId);
        agmtManSch.setAgmtNo(agmtNo);   
        agmtManSch.setYear(now.getYear());
        agmtManSch.setPeriod(now.getMonthValue());              
        agmtManSch.setSubmitDate(now);      
        agmtManSch.setCreateDate(now);
        agmtManSch.setCreateUser(userId);
        agmtManSch.setUpdateDate(now);
        agmtManSch.setUpdateUser(userId);   
        workloadDao.persist(agmtManSch);
    }
    return manningSchedule.getScheduleId();
}
```

Below is the exception I get

web - 2018-10-23 11:40:30,608 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] WARN  o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
web - 2018-10-23 11:40:30,609 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Connection has already been closed.
web - 2018-10-23 11:40:30,645 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor - Application exception overridden by rollback exception
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not prepare statement
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:147)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:155)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1419)
    at org.hibernate.Query.getResultList(Query.java:427)
    at hk.gov.devb.pwcrar.dao.ManningScheduleDao.getAllAgreementManningScheduleByAgmtIdAndGroupId(ManningScheduleDao.java:545)
    at hk.gov.devb.pwcrar.service.impl.AgreementServiceImpl.insertOrUpdateManningSchedule(AgreementServiceImpl.java:1404)
    at hk.gov.devb.pwcrar.service.impl.AgreementServiceImpl.deleteAgmtWrkldDetail(AgreementServiceImpl.java:1373)

Thx in advance!

Comment: as the error is in `insertOrUpdateManningSchedule` I think it would be better to show that code

Comment: Just added the code for it.

Comment: where are you opening / closing your connections?

Comment: It is done using spring.

Comment: <Resource auth="Container" defaultAutoCommit="false" description="PWCRAR Database" driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory" global="pwcrarDB" maxIdle="20" maxTotal="20" maxWaitMillis="500000" name="pwcrarDB" password="P@ssw0rd" removeAbandoned="true" removeAbandonedTimeout="500" type="javax.sql.DataSource" url="jdbc:sqlserver://10.82.87.151:1433;databaseName=PWCRAR_PROD_L;autoReconnect3=true;" username="sa" validationQuery="select 1"/>

Comment: try increasing `maxTotal="20" ` to maybe 200

Comment: OK let me try thx

Comment: Still gives the same error :(